# How to set up SSL for JBoss AS 7.1.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 Server

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, jboss7.x, ubuntu-12.04

I tried to set up SSL for an JBoss AS 7.1.1 installation on a Ubuntu 12.04 server.
I have already generated a private key (.pem) and a certificate signing request (.csr) with openssl, submitted it to a CA and got the signed certificate file (.pem) back.

Now, I tried already different ways how to set up SSL for my JBoss, e.g. after the instructions on https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/SSL+setup+guide. This looks as follows:

```
<connector name="https" scheme="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" socket-binding="https" enable-lookups="false" secure="true">
<ssl name="foo-ssl" password="secret" certificate-key-file="../standalone/configuration/foo.pem" certificate-file="../standalone/configuration/foo-cert.pem"/>
```

Unfortunately, during start up of JBoss AS, the following error is thrown and the https connector is not started:

Caused By: LifecycleException: protocol handler initialization failed: java.lang.Exception: Unable to load certificate key .../foo.pem (error: 06074079: digital envelope routines: EVP_PBE_CipherInit: unknown pbe algorithm)

Can anybody help me to solve this error?
Thanks in advance!

Greets,
Trinity

Comment: Well the error message is pretty clear. Have you tried using the absolute path to the file? If that work, then you can investigate how to use a relative path.

Comment: The same error comes up if I try it with the absolute path. In my opinion, the error indicates that openssl cannot decrypt the private key or something similar ("unknown pbe alogrithm")....Any further ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meanwhile I have solved the problem by removing the passphrase from my private key. Seems like openssl did not know how to decrypt my private key in pkcs#8 format....Now, it works.